# How to recurrently call function to display parent child relationship between files

Tags: java, arraylist, tree, hashmap, jtree

I have one folder ("all_folders") which contains 5 sub folders ("folder_1","folder_2","folder_3","folder_4" and "folder_5" ).
Each of these sub-folders contains 2 text files having names like "file_1.txt" ,"file_2.txt" and so on.
Each of the text file contains address to the next file say "file_1.txt" content is GOTO "file_2.txt".
In the same manner a file can have multiple address and those file in turn can have address of other files.
Basically its like a binary tree.I want a user to input a file name for which he wants to know all the address the file he entered contains.
The output I want should be like a binary tree. I.e like file_10 contains address of file file_7 , file_8 and file_9.
Again file_9 contains address of file_6 and file_4.
file_8 contains address of file_5.
file_7 doesn't contain any address of file and so on....
I have attached the image of the output which I want and the files and folder i have.

Till now I have written the below code in which i am storing the address which file_10 contains (assuming user entered file_10) in a array list and able to print that.
But now I want this code to repeat till a file doesn't have any address (see image for the output required).
I am planning to use JTree to display output as a binary tree as shown in image.
But that is the second thing and first I need to get the output.

1. I need help on how we can repeatedly call function to show all file addresses.
2. Secondly I am using array list but my concern is , do I need to have as many array list as many level of parent child relationship I have in my tree.
   Because at present I just only have 5 folders and 10 files but it may increase.so there will be lot many array list.

Can you please help me to achieve this output.
As this is a big code i have tried to write comments wherever possible but sorry as i might not be following good practices in the code as I am a beginner.

Output Image:
[image: Output Required]

Attached all_folder files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9hvL6YZBpoTRkVYV0dUWEU5V2M

My Code is as below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindFile
{
    String result;
    static ArrayList<String> storeAllFileName = new ArrayList<String>(); // This array list will store all file names from all the sub-folders of all_folders
    static int i = 0;

    public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String directoryName)
        {
            File directory = new File(directoryName);
            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
            for (File file : fList)
                {
                    if (file.isFile())
                        {
                            if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) // Checking if the file is
                                                                                                        // a text file
                                {
                                    storeAllFileName.add(file.getName().toLowerCase());
                                    i++;
                                }
                        } else if (file.isDirectory())
                        {
                            listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            recurrenceFileFind();
        }

    public static void recurrenceFileFind() throws FileNotFoundException
        {
            FindFile FindFile = new FindFile();

            String fileName = "file_10.txt"; // Hardcoded this value assuming user
                                                                                // have entered file_10.txt
            final String directoryName = "C:\\all_folders"; // Hardcoded this value
                                                                                                            // assuming all folder
                                                                                                            // of user are placed in
                                                                                                            // C:\all_folders
                                                                                                            // directory

            FindFile.listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(directoryName);
            FindFile.searchDirectory(new File(directoryName), fileName);

            System.out.println("\nFile Found at: " + FindFile.getResult());
            String filedirectoryName = FindFile.getResult(); // Passing the location
                                                                                                                // of the file found
                                                                                                                // at so that now we
                                                                                                                // can read the text
                                                                                                                // of the file and
                                                                                                                // search for the
                                                                                                                // address of child
                                                                                                                // files

            File file = new File(filedirectoryName);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

            ArrayList<String> viewText = new ArrayList<String>(); // This array list
                                                                                                                        // will store the
                                                                                                                        // content of the
                                                                                                                        // file

            while (in.hasNext())
                {
                    viewText.add(in.next().toLowerCase()); // Store the content of file
                                                                                                    // in a array list viewText
                }

            ArrayList<String> comparingList = new ArrayList<String>(viewText); // copy
                                                                                                                                                    // viewText
                                                                                                                                                    // array
                                                                                                                                                    // List
                                                                                                                                                    // to
                                                                                                                                                    // new
                                                                                                                                                    // array
                                                                                                                                                    // list
                                                                                                                                                    // comparingList

            comparingList.retainAll(storeAllFileName); // store only those address
                                                                                                    // in the comparingList for
                                                                                                    // which we have file with
                                                                                                    // that name in any of the
                                                                                                    // sub-folder, as the file
                                                                                                    // can have extra content
                                                                                                    // like GOTO or any other
                                                                                                    // words

            System.out.println("\n\"" + file.getName() + "\"" + " contains below files:");

            allListPrint(comparingList); // printing address of files which the
                                                                        // parent file contains

        }

    public void searchDirectory(File directory, String fileNameToSearch)
        {

            if (directory.isDirectory())
                {
                    search(directory, fileNameToSearch);
                } else
                {
                    System.out.println(directory.getAbsoluteFile() + " is not a directory!");
                }

        }

    private void search(File directory, String fileNameToSearch)

        {
            if (directory.isDirectory())
                {
                    System.out.println("Searching directory ... " + directory.getAbsoluteFile());
                    if (directory.canRead())
                        {
                            for (File temp : directory.listFiles())
                                {
                                    if (temp.isDirectory())
                                        {
                                            search(temp, fileNameToSearch);
                                        } else
                                        {
                                            if (fileNameToSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.getName().toLowerCase()))
                                                {
                                                    result = (temp.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                                                }

                                        }
                                }

                        } else
                        {
                            System.out.println(directory.getAbsoluteFile() + "Permission Denied");
                        }
                }

        }

    private static void allListPrint(ArrayList<String> List) // method to print
                                                                                                                        // array list
        {
            Iterator<String> itr = List.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext())
                {
                    System.out.println(itr.next());
                }

        }

    public String getResult()
        {
            return result;
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a binary tree? Because the tree you have here is not binary. If your tree is binary each file can point to at most two other files.

Comment: Yeah you can consider it as simple tree, it can have any combination.

Comment: I am still looking for answer on this not able to implement :(

Comment: can all files be placed in one folder or folder structure matters?

Comment: actually the folder structure matters

Comment: To update the `HashMap` in program below read folders and then files inside each folder. It should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution. I assume you can create `HashMap<String,Node>` from the directory of files yourself. I just manually created such `HashMap` to save time. But it's quite straightforward to do automatically. In one pass you read all files and create a `Node`for each file, and in the second pass you update their `children` field.

```
class Node {

String name;
List<Node> children = new ArrayList();

public Node(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}

public class FileTree {

//recursive function for returning children
public void retChildHeirarchy(Node n) {

    if (n == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (Node child : n.children) {
        retChildHeirarchy(child);
        System.out.println(child.name);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<String, Node> treeStructure = new HashMap<>();

    /*To save time, I manually create the nodes and update HashMap of Nodes 
     but you can do it automatically. 
     */
    Node f4 = new Node("file_4");
    Node f6 = new Node("file_6");
    Node f7 = new Node("file_7");
    Node f8 = new Node("file_8");
    Node f9 = new Node("file_9");
    Node f10 = new Node("file_10");

    //update f_10
    f10.children.add(f9);
    f10.children.add(f8);
    f10.children.add(f7);
    //update f9
    f9.children.add(f6);
    f9.children.add(f4);

    treeStructure.put("file_4", f4);
    treeStructure.put("file_6", f6);
    treeStructure.put("file_7", f7);
    treeStructure.put("file_8", f8);
    treeStructure.put("file_9", f9);
    treeStructure.put("file_10", f10);

    FileTree ft = new FileTree();
    //call the recursive function for the Node that you want: 
    ft.retChildHeirarchy(f9);
    }
}
```

An the output is as follows. Note for `f10` the recursive function works ok, but when manually updating `f10` I didn't add 5, 2 3, and 1 to the list of its children.

```
ft.retChildHeirarchy(f9);

    file_6
    file_4

ft.retChildHeirarchy(f10);

    file_6
    file_4
    file_9
    file_8
    file_7
```